# ansible + how to run ansible interactive like bash script that ask questions

Tags: linux, bash, ansible

we want to create ansible code that ask interactive questions like the bash script

for now we have the following bash script, with diff 43 Questions , that finally create `ini` file according to our Questions

```
bash /home/gentwo.bash

how many machines?23
how many datanode services?
IP address for first machine - andnenda01?

.
.
.


---
```

as we know we cant do the same with ansible as the following:

```
- hosts: 17.12.22.56
  gather_facts: yes
  vars:
    app_name: interactive process
    ansible_user: root
    ansible_password: XXXXXXXXXXX

  tasks:
    - name: interactive process
      script: "/home/gentwo.bash"
      register: results
```

so what is the equivalent approach with ansible?

Comment: I will start by saying that I don't think Ansible is really the right tool for an interactive task like this...but if you really want to go down this road, the [prompt](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html) module allows you to prompt for user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `prompts` for interactive input

e.g. from docs:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  vars_prompt:

    - name: username
      prompt: What is your username?
      private: no

    - name: password
      prompt: What is your password?

  tasks:

    - name: Print a message
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: 'Logging in as {{ username }}'
```

Ansible Doc: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html